# XML Import into R Questions

Tags: r, xml

so I picked up this new brewing beer control equipment and as first test I've just recorded the temperature data from the sensor...  it stores the output data as an .XML file to an SD card, and here is a few sample records of it..  when I try to import this into R I get an error...

[image]

```
Error: 1: Couldn't find end of Start Tag dat line 4  
2: PCDATA invalid Char value 25  
3: expected '>'  
4: Opening and ending tag mismatch: Tlog line 3 and dat  
5: PCDATA invalid Char value 25  
6: Opening and ending tag mismatch: datalog line 2 and Tlog  
7: Extra content at the end of the document
```

but, I was looking at it and this weird box with ? mark is inside the open/close dat tag,
also I am not a XLM expert by any means and I am not sure why it logs it with this weird
character, but I removed it and then it imported fine... I guess my question is what is it ?
and can I put something into the R code to remove it ? maybe I can use find and replace, but just wondering why this is there to begin with...

what I am using right now is simple like:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlToDataFrame("test.xml")
```

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: It looks to me as if your "box" is a `[` followed by a `]`.  [But I can't be sure because you've posted an image - another reason in addition to the above... ;=)] In which case, I think your [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) is malformed.  That suggests your best option it to preprocess the XML to remove the `[]`s and then import it.

Comment: Please copy/paste the content of XML into your post and not as an image. Your issue may be an encoding one.

Comment: the reason why I posted the images is because when I posted the data, the offending issue wasn't visible, it somehow went away, so that's why....  I think I have solved the issue by just removing the offending brackets, but why the device creates them is a mystery to me.

Comment: I also hate the XML format, I wishes the makers just created a flat file, this is what I did on my own device - sometimes commercial products are crap...